# Nginx identical query parameters

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How to get identical query parameters in Nginx? Parameter **phone** may be more two.

Sample query string:

`/subscriber?action=getSubscriptions&phone=123456789&phone=987654321`

Or reformat in

`/subscriber?action=getSubscriptions&phone[]=123456789&phone[]=987654321`

Comment: Why do you need to get them in nginx?

Comment: PHP can not parse this url

Comment: Fix the page that generates that url.

Comment: This method is described in the documentation of the partners. I can not change the input parameters.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792

Comment: I used this solution, but it is not beautiful )

Comment: Anyway, it's not nginx's job to fix PHP bugs